# Windows container with ACI - network access problem

Tags: networking, windows-container, azure-container-instances

I have windows container running in ACI with public address but with specific TCP port - 7070.
I've set it with following command:

```
az container create --name xxxxxx --resource-group xxxxx --image xxxxx.azurecr.io/xxxxx:yyy --registry-login-server xxxxxx --registry-username xxxxxx --dns-name-label xxxxxxx --command-line xxxxx --os-type Windows --registry-password xxxxx --ports 7070 --protocol TCP --ip-address Public
```

It runs ok as far as I can tell, but I cannot access application listening on 7070 port.

```
> telnet xxxxxx 7070
Connecting To xxxxx...Could not open connection to the host, on port 7070: Connect failed
```

Obviously when running locally (Docker for Windows) it works smoothly.

What can I do here ?

I assume there might be some security/firewall on public IP level, but public IP that my container was given is not available for me to manage - at least my azure portal "Public IP addresses" service is not showing it.
Any suggestion/idea where to search for solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like ACI ports work only for HTTP "alike" connections.
I've tried multiple ports with just TCP sockets to no luck, but as soon as I've setup http server - all works smoothly.
So at least for me ACI with windows containers is useless.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your ACI has not propagated well. You could try to deploy it again after a while. Possibly, the port 7070 is forbidden on your current machine or local network where you are telneting from. You might check some security/firewall on your on-premise network.

Comment: I tried so far multiple times (three times per each variation of container). 

I cannot believe in issue on my local side of network because I tried:
* accessing TCP 7070 on other external machines - works
* accessing my ACI TCP 7070 from other external machines - does not work.

I'm preparing special container with active listeners of multiple ports/protocols to figure out if there will be success for any other port or it is some other problem. Unfortunately TCP 7070 is proprietary dependency I cannot omit, hence last effort will be old good classic VM